# How to show that a spacetime metric is satisfied by certain Killing vectors?

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the spacetime with metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ ,given in coordinates $x^{\mu} = (x^1, x^2, x^3, x^4) = (t, \phi, r, z)$, where

$ g_{\mu\nu} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
-1 & -\sqrt{2}r^2  & 0 & 0 \\
-\sqrt{2}r^2 & r^2(1-r^2) & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & (1+r^2)^{-1} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$

How would I show that this metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, has the Killing vectors $X_1 = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$, $X_2 = \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$ and $X_3 = \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$?

Comment: What is the definition of a Killing vec. field?

Comment: A Killing vector field, X, fulfills LXg=0 where L is the Lie derivative, g is a metric.   $\nabla_{mu}X_{nu} + \nabla_{\nu}X_{\mu}=0$

Comment: The most obvious way would be to plug these various choices of $X$ into the left side of Killing's equation, I suppose.